Error Propagation of an Integral in given bins
I have an array of x, y and yerr values as follows:
x_values22 = np.array([6.25, 6.75, 7.10, 7.30, 7.50, 7.70, 7.90, 8.10, 8.30, 8.50, 8.70, 8.90, 9.10])
x_values2 = x_values22 -0.15
x_values = np.power(10, x_values2)    

y_values2 = np.array([-1.507240, -1.742321, -1.747147, -1.365523, -1.500313, -1.458421,-1.563837, -1.548214, -1.628932, -1.716699, -1.744727, -1.844664,-1.991400])
y_values = np.power(10, y_values2)             

y_err2 = np.array([0.3016322, 0.1583615, 0.1382949, 0.0876650, 0.1236915,0.1048297, 0.0668145, 0.0429691, 0.0554418, 0.0271434, 0.0627314, 0.0516294, 0.0255467])
y_err = np.power(10, y_err2)

Then I just do a simple trapezoidal integral for y in a given x-range as follows :
integrals= {}

for x_values_min, x_values_max in x_ranges:
    y_slice = y_values[(x_values >= x_values_min) & (x_values <= x_values_max)]
    y_err_slice = y_err[(x_values >= x_values_min) & (x_values <= x_values_max)]
    
    integral = np.abs(trapz(y_slice, x=x_values[(x_values >= x_values_min) & (x_values <= x_values_max)]))
    integral_err = np.sqrt(np.sum(y_err_slice**2))  # Sum of errors in quadrature
    
    key = "result_{:.2f}".format(((np.log10(x_values_min) + np.log10(x_values_max))/2)).replace('.', '_')
    
    integrals[key] = (integral, integral_err)
    
    print("Integral of y_values between {0:.2f} and {1:.2f}: {2:.4f} ± {3:.4f}".format(
        x_values_min, x_values_max, integral, integral_err))

The errors are really small (result 556337.6972 ± 2.6887 etc) so I know there is a mistake somewhere but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated. I think it is either how I am calculating the errors, or np.power(10 ... ) of the values are messing up things.

It's difficult for others to look at a program and say where a minor error is. Not impossible, but others might not invest the time to find it. My advice is to make the problem simpler in some way so that you know exactly what the expected result should be at each step, and then see where the actual results diverge from expected. E.g. consider just one interval and make it 0 to 1 or something like that. If that works, then change one thing at a time until you get back to the original problem and it works, or you found the bug along the way.
